# How to make method spit out different things

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, methods, nsmanagedobject

I'm struggling to get this to work. I have a function, thats suppose to tape into coreData and grab

1. All Routines
2. A certain routine

if it does:

1 -> it needs to output routineNames as a NSArray
2 -> then just output it as a NSManagedObject.

```
var routineNames:AnyObject!
func GetRoutines(type: String) -> AnyObject {

    routineNames = []

    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Routines")

    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: false)
    let sortDescriptors = [sort]

    request.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)

    if results?.count > 0 {

        if type == "AllRoutines" {

            for result: AnyObject in results! {

                if result.valueForKey("name") != nil {

                    routineNames.append(result.valueForKey("name") as String)

                    //println(routineNames)

                }

            }

        } else {

            for result: AnyObject in results! {

                if result.valueForKey("name") as String == type {

                  routineNames = result

                }
            }

        }
    }
    return routineNames
}
```

Comment: It'll probably be easier to use two functions. One to retrieve a specific object and one to retrieve all objects. And instead of fetching all and checking if the type = "AllRoutines" just use an NSPredicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it like this:

```
func GetRoutines(type: String) -> AnyObject {

    routineNames = []

    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Routines")

    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: false)
    let sortDescriptors = [sort]

    request.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)

    if results?.count > 0 {

        if type == "AllRoutines" {

            for result: AnyObject in results! {

                if result.valueForKey("name") != nil {

                    routineNames.append(result.valueForKey("name") as String)

                    //println(routineNames)

                }

            }

        } else {

            for result: AnyObject in results! {

                if result.valueForKey("name") as String == type {

                    println(result)

                    return result

                }
            }

        }
    }
    return results!
}
```